# How to find the index without using which(), match(), %in%?

Tags: r, loops, max

I am unable to find the index position of my max_value without using which(), match(), %in%

```
vect_1 <- c(2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 10, 7, 6, 9, 8)

n <- length(vect_1)
max_value <- vect_1[1]

for (i in 1:n) {
  if (vect_1[i] > max_value) {
    max_value <- vect_1[i]
  }
  if (max_value == vect_1[i]) {
    print(i)
  }
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

I know the `max_value` is `10` but I am unable to get `i == 6` only

Comment: The way you have your code, `i` is the index, not the value. The max value is 10. 10 is the 6th value. `vect_1[6]` is 10. Use `print(i)` to print the index. Use `print(vect_1[i])` to print the value at the index.

Comment: Adding, if you want to save the index of the max value, then you need a separate object for that, `i_max` or something. To complete your loop, `i` needs to take every value along the vector. So you need a separate object to to store the index of the maximum.

Comment: And if you only want to print the max value and it's index, then you need to do your printing *after* the loop, not *inside* the loop.

Comment: And you could use `which.max`, though figuring out these 'what's happening when' (and why) in loops is really rather important.

Comment: `Position(function(x) x == sort(v, decreasing = T)[1], v)` may be interesting to explore. It uses loops under the hood, you can look at the definition by typing `Position` in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should look like this:

```
n <- length(vect_1)
max_value <- vect_1[1]
max_value_idx <- 1

for (i in 1:n) {
  if (vect_1[i] > max_value) {
    max_value <- vect_1[i]
    max_value_idx <- i
  }
}
print(paste0("Max value: ", max_value," Index: ",max_value_idx))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `print`, each iteration will print something to the console. I think we never need `print` in serious `R` loops, and seldom need `for` loops in serious R. Regardless, here are two separate ideas of a solution, (where I think you're mixing up the two).

### 1. Max. is known

In this case we just compare each element with `max_value` and `if` they match, store the `i`ndex in the `res`ult.

```
n <- length(vect_1)
res <- NA

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  if (vect_1[i] == max_value) {
    res <- i
  }
}
res
# [1] 6
```

### 2. Max. is unknown

In this case, we don't know the max yet. We want a starting value `mx` that is smaller than everything that may come, which is `-Inf`. `if` we get something greater, we update `mx` and store the index in the `res`ult.

```
n <- length(vect_1)
mx <- -Inf
res <- NA

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  if (vect_1[i] > mx) {
    mx <- vect_1[i]
    res <- i
  }
}
mx
# [1] 10

res
# [1] 6
```

### Concluding remark

Note, that I consider this might be a nice task for practicing `for` loops and train respective thinking. However there's no point to use the `R` language for that, where we simply may do

```
which.max(vect_1)
# [1] 6
```

which gives the same result (if there are no ties).

Comment: Could you explain what is the point of initializing the initial variable `mx`  as -inf instead of assigning the first element in the list to it? And what is the difference between the first and the second solution (if we are only looking for an index), since regardless of whether we know the place of the largest number or not, the second solution will show it to us and so must perform the comparison operation?

Comment: @KacZdr If we initialize `mx` with the fist element, the first iteration compares something with itself, admittedly technically that would not make much difference unless it's not `NA` or something. The second solution is just intended as an extension, if the maximum is unknown.